# Find out if a session with a particular id has expired

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cron

I am creating an upload feature that stores a user uploaded file on the server with the user's session-id as its name. Now, I want to keep this file on the server only till that session is active.

So, my question is, how can I determine from the session-id, whether a session is active or expired so that in the later case I can safely delete the user uploaded file.

This I want to do as a cleanup at particular intervals maybe by using a cron job, though I have never used it before.

Comment: As far as I remember it's webserver's job to remove expired sessions, so maybe you can hook into this mechanism?

Comment: @Mchl yes you are right that it is the server's job to remove expired sessions but i don't want to do that. i want to remove a user uploaded file if his session is expired or else there would be a lot of unwanted files taking up my server's space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just rely on session.gc_maxlifetime because after this time the session is marked as garbage and the garbage collector starts only with a probability of 1% by default ( session.gc_probability).

The better approach IMHO is to handle yourserlf the expired data.

You can for instance start the time and save it into a session variable:

```
<?php $_SESSION['last_seen'] = time();//Update this value on each user interaction. ?>
```

Later..via cron you can do something like this:

```
<?php
//Get the session id from file name and store it into the $sid variable;
session_id($sid);//try to resume the old session
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['last_seen']) && $_SESSION['last_seen'] > $timeout){//Session is expired
  //delete file
  session_destroy();
}else if (!isset($_SESSION['last_seen')){ //already garbaged
  //delete  file
  session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Not tested...just an idea

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the exact same thing. One solution would be to define a custom garbage collector function with [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). In this custom function you would delete the uploaded files associated with the session and then delete the session from disk. The only problem I see it's that you will have to define the rest of the session handlers as well:

```
bool session_set_save_handler ( callback $open, 
                                callback $close, 
                                callback $read, 
                                callback $write, 
                                callback $destroy, 
                                callback $gc )
```

This is easy if you don't rely on PHP to handle sessions. Is there a way to call the default handler functions of PHP from a custom handler function?

Answer (score 0):

Intervals can be made like this - someone opens your web -> php script is running -> it checks if files is time-outed -> delete time-oted files

And no CRON needed :-)

It is nearly impossible to determinate due to lack of information if user closed or not the browser window ( if he don't closes it but turn sleep mode on and come back in 2 days - session is still active AFAIK ) - 
only idea to slove this problem in best manner this is to use own session engine with AJAX checking.

Comment: thats a good tip to keep away from the cron :) but there should be someway to know if a session is expired, maybe by going through the session files. comparing its date of creation with the time lapsed or something.

Comment: Isn't simplier to test time-out of file ? And store last-access in session, just for killing older sessions ( yes, it is possible to keep one session for 2 days )