# PHP to get users login status maintain a record in a mysql table. How to delete this record on logout, browser close and session expiry

Tags: php, authentication

I need to get the users logged in status in php. When he login to website am inserting a record to a table called "users_login_status" and it will be deleted when he log out.
Now if the browser closed or session expired means how can i trace and delete record of that particular user in "users_login_status" table?

Comment: why are you inserting in database table why not just using sessions and cookies for user status ?

Comment: I need to show the list of logged in users for administrator module. Do we have any other better way??

Comment: i think you can take a column in your user table "status" where you can set value 1 for logged in user and 0 for rest. this way you can fetch list of logged in user in admin panel too

Comment: Good idea!  But how can i change the status to 0 when browser closed or session expired?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753687/find-out-if-a-session-with-a-particular-id-has-expired and this would  help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603197/php-do-something-when-session-gets-expired

Answer (score 0):

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

Use this, when they return to the browser, they should be logged out.

Comment: you can define the lifetime of your cookie here in secs for example if you want your cookie to be expire after two hrs use can use like session_set_cookie_params(2*60*60);