# How to know if PHP SESSION variable is expired?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I found out that `isset($_SESSION['hash'])` returns true even if the variable has expired(but does not let me use it). Is there any way to check if it has expired? Thank you!

Comment: There seems to be a lot of [related info](https://www.bing.com/search?q=check+if+php+session+variable+is+expired) readily available to help you answer this.  What research have you done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out if a session with a particular id has expired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753687/find-out-if-a-session-with-a-particular-id-has-expired)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) { session_start(); }
```

Comment: shouldn't I run `session_start();` before doing that check? I understood that if I do not run `session_start();` it is as if there has never been a session.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are getting at now, you will need to keep track of the session time your self using another session the correct answer in this post explains it better than I can: [Find out if a session with a particular id has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753687/find-out-if-a-session-with-a-particular-id-has-expired)